# Intermittently breaking tests in my hand-rolled Sinatra app. Related to file processing?

Tags: ruby, debugging, sinatra

Summary: After adding logic to save user account data, my code seems to work fine and sometimes all my (many) tests pass. But sometimes they fail seemingly randomly, with `/tmp` test files not being deleted during testing.

In my hand-rolled Ruby/Sinatra ["to do list" program](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo), I added user accounts and can now save data to user files (.yml format) as well as tmp files for people who aren't logged in. Yay!

As far as I can tell, the code works fine. All tests pass...but only sometimes. Sometimes, the tests related to my new file processing methods fail. Here's a sample:

```
# Running:

....EF..........................

Finished in 3.930466s, 8.1415 runs/s, 53.1744 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ToDoTest#test_post_newtask:
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - tmp/1.yml
    C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_todo.rb:404:in `delete'
    C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_todo.rb:404:in `block (2 levels) in teardown'
    C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_todo.rb:404:in `each'
    C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_todo.rb:404:in `block in teardown'


  2) Failure:
ToDoTest#test_get_deleted [C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_todo.rb:167]:
Expected false to be truthy.

32 runs, 209 assertions, 1 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib" -I"C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/test_task.rb" "test/test_task_store.rb" "test/test_todo.rb" "test/test_todo_helpers.rb" "test/test_users.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => default => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is only a *sample*, because sometimes many more tests fail or have errors. It's weirdly random. I noticed that my tests, which result in a lot `/tmp` files being made and deleted very rapidly, sometimes failed to delete some files, and as a result some would be left behind. If I reran my tests when there were some undeleted files in `/tmp`, there would be even more (again, random) errors.

One common error I saw, which I never saw before adding the new file processing commands, is this one: `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal`. I looked this up on SO but there seems to be only (irrelevant-seeming) Rails stuff. This is a Sinatra program running on Windows. So could I replicate the tests in my Ubuntu VM? Yes I could. Precisely the same sort of error pattern.

Anyway, I suspected that system commands were not finishing before execution continued. But apparently not. I tried putting "sleep 2" after all my system commands, and I *still* got a random failing test and cruft left in `/tmp`. I also tried using threads, which I have never used before, like this:

```
delr = Thread.new do
  File.delete(@store.path) # seems to help to add this here...
end
delr.join
```

But that didn't help.

One other thing...I'm teaching myself and this is probably not the way it's supposed to be done, but...all of my `get` methods are preceded by a check of my session[:id] variable to see if the user is logged in, and to see if the correct datafile is loaded. I don't know if that's relevant but it might be.

Any ideas on what the problem could be or how to fix it?

Comment: I've got a sneaking suspicion that your tests are either order-dependent or you're not waiting for whatever code is going on to finish before you move on to the next test. I'm not sure why you're using a thread to delete a file. Just delete it with a blocking call.

Comment: I think you're right about your diagnosis... What do you mean by "blocking call"? Is it just using [backticks](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html)?

Comment: I mean calls like `File.unlink` are blocking, your code won't advanced to the next statement until that one's done. Non-blocking calls finish at some arbitrary point in the future. These can be done with threads, fibers, or some other mechanism like a callback function.

Comment: OK thanks! Appreciate it!